# Merge two files with similar column entries

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix

I have a few files which contains user name and data transfer rate in MB/s. This data is collected for a year, and for each month the report is saved in 12 different files. I have to merge all the files to prepare the final report.

Files are as below

```
Filename1 : January

#User Name           #Data Transferred

A. Paul                       300004
Jason                        600000
Mayur Pandey             40000
Kelly H                       459000
Ryan M                       349000


Filename2 : March 

#User Name           #Data Transferred

Senthl V R                  600000
Mayur Pandey                40000
Kelly H                     459000
Pratap S                    349000
A. Paul                     300004
```

Similarly I have 10 more files. I have to merge all these files to one file and the final output should be like below:

```
Final Report:

#Username     #January      ....     #March ......... #December      #Total

A. Paul        300004                300004            Not available 600008
Pratap S       Not availanble        30000             32000         7899887
Kelly H        459000                459000            459000        3424448274
Mayur Pandey   40000                 400000            400000        242424442
Senthl V R     Not available         600000            34544         53546464
Jason          600000                Not available     3434343       43434355
```

I need a Perl script to automate this rather using Excel or doing it manually.

These reports are generated monthly and names are not stored in sorted order. Names are stored in recent user who has used data transfer facility. Also there are occasions when a user has not used data transfer at all for a particular month; in this case the name of the user will not appear in the monthly report file. In this case I have to add *not available* in the month name column.

All the fields or column values are separated by \t TAB and stored in normal txt files.

Thank you

Comment: I am not able to make any logic for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It's more fiddly than truly difficult.  The file names become column headings in the outputs.  You'll probably treat the order of the file names on the command line as the order they appear as output columns; otherwise, you build in too much knowledge.   As you read each file, you'll split the line into name and number.  You'll need a hash indexed by the name, and the values will either be a reference to a hash or a reference to an array.

The output is relatively straight-forward.  You decide on an order to present the names (your sample output has no discernible order), and then step through the hash in that sequence.  For each entry, you can print the value in each column, spotting when there are missing entries and printing `Not available' or thereabouts when the value is missing.  You can accumulate the total for the row as you go, and likewise the overall total.

You probably want to right-justify the numbers, rather than left justifying them.

Answer (score 0):

Although the following code is not very smart somewhere , but I think it can solve your problem.

```
use warnings;
my @file_list=("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
my %priorities=(   
    January=>1,
    February=>2,
    March=>3,
    April=>4,
    May=>5,
    June=>6,
    July=>7,
    August=>8,
    September=>9,
    October=>10,
    November=>11,
    December=>12
);    
my %report_datas=();    
foreach my $file_name (@file_list) {
    open FH , "<" , $file_name or die("can not open file");
    $skip_line=0;
    while(<FH>) {
            $skip_line++;
        next until $skip_line>2;    #skip the header(first two lines)
        chomp;

        if(/[^\d]+/) {         #get the name
            $name=$&;
            $name=~s/\s+$//;   #strip the empty chars at the end 
        }
        if(/[\d]+/) {        #get the transfer data
            $data=$&;
        }

        $month=$file_name;
        $report_datas{$name}{$month}=$data if not exists $report_datas{$name}{$month};  
        $report_datas{$name}{"priority"}=$priorities{$month};              #always store the latest month while we are reading file_name from January to December 
   }
   close FH;
}

#sort names by the month of using transfer data
@sorted_names = sort { $report_datas{$a}{"priority"} <=> $report_datas{$b}{"priority"} } keys %report_datas;  

#print result
printf "%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s%-18s\n\n","#Username","#January","#February","#March","#April","#May","#June","#July","#August","#September","#October","#November","#December","#Total";
foreach my $name (@sorted_names) {
    my $sum=0;
    printf "%-18s",$name;
    foreach my $month (@file_list) {
        if ( exists $report_datas{$name}{$month}) {
            printf "%-18d",$report_datas{$name}{$month};
        $sum+=$report_datas{$name}{$month};
        } else {
        printf "%-18s","Not available";
        }
    }

    print "$sum\n";
}
```